# Why does data and data$value work differently in ggplot and geom_line?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following R code to plot from a given data in a listing format called probData_com. This code is fine but the problem is if I replace "ranks", "value", and "variable" inside the ggplot and the geom_line by dat$ranks, dat$value, and dat$variable, then 'g' only show the last plot three times. Can anyone tell me why it is happening?

```
    g <- list()
    for(i in 1:3)
    {
        probData <- probData_com[[i]]
        colnames(probData) <- c("ranks","SH0","SH1","EH0","EH1","AH0","AH1")
        dat <- melt(probData, id.var = "ranks")

        ey_val <- ifelse(effectType == "binary", i-1,
                         ifelse(i==1, 0, paste0("U(",i-2,", ", i-1,")")))
        eySm <- ifelse(effectType == "binary", "ey = ", "ey ~ ")

        g[[i]] = ggplot(dat, aes(x = ranks, y = value, group = variable,
                                 colour = variable)) +
            geom_line(aes(linetype = variable), size = 1.5) +
            labs(x = "Ranks", y = "p(rank | effect)", size = 20,
                 subtitle = paste0(eySm, ey_val, ", e.one = ", e.one)) +
            theme(legend.title = element_blank(),
                  axis.title.x = element_text(size = rel(.7)),
                  axis.title.y = element_text(size = rel(.7)))
    }
```

g

Comment: Don't use `$` inside `aes`. `ggplot` uses something called non-standard evaluation, and you should pass bare variable names in most cases. For programming purposes you can use `aes_` and `aes_string`.

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problems

Comment: What if I need to pass something like:                                                    
 ggplot(dat, aes_string(x = dat[,1], y = "value",
                                        group = "variable", col = "variable")).                          where I do not know the first column's name in advance. will aes_string still work?

Comment: use `x = names(dat_melt)[[1]]`

Comment: To expand on what Axeman just said, you want to use `x = names(dat_melt)[[1]]` because that returns a single name, while your original attempt `x = dat[,1]` returns not the name, but the entire column vector.